# JavaFX: Button hover stuck after opening new Stage

Tags: javafx, hover, stage

So I'm making a game in JavaFX where i have a main Stage and I want a message to pop up before the game starts. The pop up will go away when you hit space (to start the game). To initiate a new game (after game over) you have to click a "new game"-button on the main stage.

This works, but theres just one problem. Since the popup window is activated right after the user clicks "New Game", the button gets stuck in hover. So after a new game has started the button has still a lighter shade. I don't want to remove the hover effect, but I want it to go away as soon as the game has started. What I believe is happening is that when the popup stage is opened, the main stage beneath doesn't register mouse movement so that it doesn't get to remove the hover.

Here is the code for the popup that is located in controller for main Stage:

```
public void showPopUp() {

    try {

        Stage stage = new Stage();

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("popUp.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 210,55);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);

        stage.show();

        scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            if ((e.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE)) {
                stage.close();
                startGame();
            }
        });

    } catch (IOException ieo) {
        ieo.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And here's a recording of the issue:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/y1d778l92mmknzb/Snake%20Game%20Recording.mov?dl=0

Comment: have you tried button.setFocused(false);

Comment: @Austin There no such command.